# Group Binary Data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am playing around with binary data.

I have test data in columns in the following manner:

```
       A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
       -----------------------------------------------------
       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
```

***`1`*** is indicating that the system was on and **`0`** indicating that the system was off.

I have a way to figure out a way to summarize the gaps between the *on/off* transition of these systems.

For example:

- for the first row, it stops working after `I`
- for the second row, it works from  `E` to `G` and then works again in `I` and `M` but is off during others.

I see my result in the following form (`table1`)

```
    row-number   value      grp_num     num       Range
    ------------  -----     --------    ------    ------ 
    1              1           1          9         A-I
    1              0           2          5         J-N
    2              0           1          4         A-D
    2              1           2          3         E-G
    2              0           3          1         H-H
    2              1           4          2         I-J
    2              0           5          2         K-L
    2              1           6          1         M-M
    2              0           7          1         N-N
```

The code I used is this:

```
table1 <- test[,-c(1)] %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(col,val,-rowname) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  mutate(grp_num = cumsum(val != lag(val, default = -99))) %>%
  group_by(rowname,val,grp_num) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(num = n(),
                   range = paste0(first(col), "-", last(col)))
```

My question here is if my data had blank entries, how can I exclude them from being a part of a group.

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
-----------------------------------------------------
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
                1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
```

The expected result is very similar but excluding the blank values

```
         row-number   value      grp_num     num       Range
        ------------  -----     --------    ------    ------ 
        1              1           1          8         B-I
        1              0           2          5         J-N
        2              1           1          3         E-G
        2              0           2          1         H-H
        2              1           3          2         I-J
        2              0           4          2         K-L
        2              1           5          1         M-M
        2              0           6          1         N-N
```

Comment: Why `I-N`? `I` is on but you are including it in the off time. In the second row though, you have `H-H` and not including previous columns in your off time. Your output is inconsistent.

Comment: @M-- changes made. Thanks

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). I am not sure how exactly you have blanks in your data. If you share `dput(head(df, 2))` with us as an [edit] to your question, I will try to see if I can be any of help. p.s. Sorry for delayed response to your update and not including these points in my first comment. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
    mutate(rownum = row_number(), .before = 1) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rownum, names_to = "Range") %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    mutate(grpnum = rleid(value), .by = rownum) %>%
    summarise(
        num = n(),
        Range = str_c(Range[c(1, n())], collapse = "-"),
        .by = c(rownum, value, grpnum)
    )
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
  rownum value grpnum   num Range
   <int> <int>  <int> <int> <chr>
1      1     1      1     8 B-I
2      1     0      2     5 J-N
3      2     1      1     3 E-G
4      2     0      2     1 H-H
5      2     1      3     2 I-J
6      2     0      4     2 K-L
7      2     1      5     1 M-M
8      2     0      6     1 N-N
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(NA, NA), B = c(1L, NA), C = c(1L, NA), D = c(1L,
NA), E = c(1L, 1L), F = c(1L, 1L), G = c(1L, 1L), H = 1:0, I = c(1L,
1L), J = 0:1, K = c(0L, 0L), L = c(0L, 0L), M = 0:1, N = c(0L,
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```